# Who's the oldest?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, paradox

A child is born on August 19th 2016 00:12 (local time) on timezone GMT + 1.
Another child is born on August 18th 2016 23:48 (local time) on timezone GMT.
Which one is the oldest?

Note: Not sure I tagged this properly. I could use some help.

Comment: What's so complicated?

Comment: I didn't say it's complicated. Should I try to create just complicated puzzles? I just thought it was fun to get an answer.

Comment: @DavidGlickman It may also depend on how you look at it.

Comment: exactly. Define oldest. :)

Comment: No, I won't :). See, now it get's a bit more (but not much) difficult.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Legally,

> GMT child is older, as they'll celebrate/commiserate their birthday the day before GMT+1 child, despite being born 36 minutes later.
> There will be a point where GMT child is 21 years old whilst GMT+1 child is 20, for example (which would be incredibly annoying if they were attempting to go to a bar in the USA (GMT-4 to GMT-10, I believe). That's largely moot, though - since they were likely born in the UK and France, GMT+1 child can start drinking 1 year and 364 days before GMT child)

Comment: Nice explanation for the 2 ways of looking at this. Exactly what I was expecting.

Comment: I like how you work out who's oldest by who can drink first ;)

Comment: Oh. That too. Since drinking is a very important thing in life. :)

Comment: Btw, the US east coast is GMT-5 (yay us), and Hawaii is GMT-10.

Answer (score 10):

I think

> as the birth time of the first child in GMT is August 18th 2016 23:12, he is 36 minutes older than the second child. At least technically he was born 36 minutes earlier than the other child, though the former will always celebrate his birthday one day later than the latter.

Comment: Well said. Quite agree

Comment: I'd say this is correct (+1), backed your answer up with mine as well

Comment: This is right from one poit of view. I was hoping fir an explanation like.  "Chronologically...this, from society's point of view....that". I kind of hinted that in the comments. +1.

Answer (score 1):

@elias answer is correct but

> It depends who was born first. If the child born in the GMT + 1 timezone was born first then he'd be the oldest regardless of the the time in GMT. 
> Think of it this way. If you were born at 11PM on the 11th in America, lived there for 20 years then moved to England, you are not going to change your birthday to the 12th are you?

Comment: sorry, i don't get your point. what does this give to my answer?

Comment: sorry I worded that comment wrong, meant agreed with you in mine